# How to run two instances of java socket servers listenening on two different ports?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

**Scenario:**
a) Persistent connections
b) Manage each server-client communication individually
c) Protect System from propagating exceptions/errors

I tried to created two instances of server socket listeners using the following code :

**SimpleSocketServers.java**

```
public class SimpleSocketServers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port1 = 9876;
        SimpleSocketServer server1 = new SimpleSocketServer(port1);
        server1.startAndRunServer();
        System.out.println("Servers : server1 Listening on port: " + port1);

        int port2 = 9875;
        SimpleSocketServer server2 = new SimpleSocketServer(port2);
        server2.startAndRunServer();
        System.out.println("Servers : server2 Listening on port: " + port2);
    }
}
```

and

**SimpleSocketServer.java**

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class SimpleSocketServer {

        private ServerSocket serverSocket;
        private int port;

        public SimpleSocketServer(int port) {
            this.port = port;
        }

        public void startAndRunServer() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Starting Server at port " + port + " ...");
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                System.out.println("Listening for client connection ...");
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler(socket);
                requestHandler.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

class RequestHandler extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;

    RequestHandler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Client Request Response being processed...");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But, it creates only one instance as control is not returning from the constructor of first instance. Is there any possibility to get back control and run both instances of server socket listeners simultaneously? (ps: Pardon me, if it is wrong or trivial!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 Different Threads, Listening To 2 Different Ports.

```
Thread ServerThread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ServerSocket ServerSocketObject = null;
        while(true)
        {
        try {
            ServerSocketObject  = new ServerSocket(Your_Port_Number1);

                Socket SocketObject = ServerSocketObject.accept();
                // Your Code Here
                SocketObject.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    ServerSocketObject.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
});

Thread ServerThread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ServerSocket ServerSocketObject = null;
        while(true)
        {
        try {
            ServerSocketObject  = new ServerSocket(Your_Port_Number2);

                Socket SocketObject = ServerSocketObject.accept();
                // Your Code Here
                SocketObject.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    ServerSocketObject.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
});

ServerThread1.start();
ServerThread2.start();
```

Comment: You can create a class extending runnable and pass port number through constructor i know that, but this is for easy understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `SimpleSocketServer` implement `Runnable`; start a thread with itself as the `Runnable` in the constructor; and run an `accept()` *loop* in the `run()` method. At present you're blocking in the constructor waiting for a connection, and your servers will also only handle a single connection.

The more interesting question is why you want to provide the same service on two ports.

Comment: You can't isolate clients or communications problems when you are running the same code on both ports. I would expect any competent programmer to be able to turn this answer into code. This is not a free coding service.

Comment: I am wondering whether you understand that you can accept multiple connections via the same listening socket. Which is how all TCP servers work, and which is why I mentioned an accept loop.